# GA in bigquery does not show the correct result

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get GA data in Bigquery by the query below.
GA data by products, but somehow it returns no result.
Anyone knows why?

```
SELECT
  product.productSKU,
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS unique_user,
  COUNT(fullVisitorId) AS page_view,
  COUNT(DISTINCT visitId) AS unique_session
FROM
  `.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
  UNNEST(hits.product) AS product
WHERE
  hits.type = 'PAGE'
GROUP BY
  product.productSKU
```

Comment: I have tested your query in a public dataset `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` and it worked smoothly. I would advise your to perfom some data exploration. At first, `Select distinct count(hits.type) as count, hits.type FROM
  ``bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_* ``,
  unnest(hits) as hits
  group by hits.type` , so you can make sure which hits.types you have. Then query the data properly. What is the output when you execute the above query?

Comment: Thank you. and i did what you recommended then the result was EVEN and PAGE with many count. So nothin is wrong? then why I cannot?

Comment: It should return.Can you run your query using the public dataset I posted above (`bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`)? Does it return any results ? Also, can you check if your project is selected in the upper left corner of the console?

Comment: The one you gave me worked smoothly. umm so the issue should be in my data source...

Comment: next steps for you to check are: 1) Check if your project is selected (top left corner of the screen); 2) Click on your table (left inferior part of your screen), go to preview, check the hits.type and its type. Can you check both and get back to me?